# Initialize transposed numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, initialization

I want to use the Singular-Value-Decomposition of matrix `A`.

If possible I would write:

```
V, S, W.T = np.linalg.svd(A)
```

But I can't initialise an array with its transposed. 
Now I have two questions:

1. As far as I understand the python internals there is no obvious workaround for this problem. Because the call of an attribute/method of `W` requires the instance to be initialised.
   One would need something as a constructor as `@property` attribute.
2. If there is no obvious workaround, which one of the following options is better/more idiomatic.

Option 1:

```
V, S, tmp = np.linalg.svd(A)
W = tmp.T
```

Option 2:

```
V, S, W = np.empty(...), np.empty(...), np.empty(...)
V[:, :], S[:, :], W.T[:, :] = np.linalg.svd(A)
```

Comment: You could perhaps timeit the two options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 2 takes over 50% more time in my experiment. It's also harder to read.

Option 1 is good, but observe that `W` will be a view of the array `tmp`. This should not be a problem unless you do something that makes it one, like `tmp[0,0] = 0` (which modifies `W` too).

I would go with

```
W = np.linalg.svd(A)
W = W.T
```

which runs in the same time as the version with `tmp` (and it still makes W a view) but does not create another name by which the same data can be accessed.